# Any recommendations for a portable wearable that can continuously monitor ECG?

Tags: wearable-technology

I am looking for a wearable or a similar portable device with the following requirements:

- Heart Rate monitoring
- Supports **continuous** ECG monitoring capabilities (especially for Atrial fibrillation)
- Supports wireless connection to Android Smartphones for alerts
- Has attained some form of accreditation or clearance either by the FDA or its EU Equivalent

It should also preferably have any of the following:

- Some form of electronic blood pressure monitoring
- Fall detection.

The immediate candidates to mind include:

- Samsung Galaxy Watch 3
- Samsung Galaxy Watch Active 2
- Fitbit Sense

But they do require the wearer to actively take an ECG reading, if I understood them correctly i.e. placing fingers on contact points or the like, then actively taking a reading (Although if the wearer can continuously trigger active readings by just leaving the fingers on or something ad-hoc it would be acceptable too)

I apologize if this is the wrong site to ask, but my understanding of this site, based on [What is Hardware?](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265/what-is-hardware) it seems like this is the right site based on the above link's definition of Hardware:

> Hardware is any primarily electronic item that can perform more than one task, designed to interface with, connect to, or be, a primary computing platform in day-to-day operation.

Where the primary computing platform is a smartphone, and the device recommendation is electronic in nature.